# Apache Qpid List of REST end points

Tags: messagebroker, qpid

**Applicable to Qpid Java broker 0.32 onwards, not sure of other Qpid Broker versions ( c++ etc.)**

For my projects I was trying to **explore various REST end points** however failed to found them in Qpid documentation and online.

Therefore figured out a way to extract REST end points which are accessible and have various possible operations and parameter support. This greatly helped me, I hope this helps to other community members.

**Sharing REST end points here for reference.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="QpidApiDocs_files/apidocs.css">
<title>Qpid API</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="api">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="type">Type</th>
<th class="path">Path</th>
<th class="description">Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/accesscontrolprovider">AccessControlProvider</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/accesscontrolprovider</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/accesscontrolprovider</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/authenticationprovider">AuthenticationProvider</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/authenticationprovider</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/authenticationprovider</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/binding">Binding</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/binding</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/binding</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/broker">Broker</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/broker</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/broker</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/brokerloginclusionrule">BrokerLogInclusionRule</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/brokerloginclusionrule</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/brokerloginclusionrule</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/brokerlogger">BrokerLogger</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/brokerlogger</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/brokerlogger</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/connection">Connection</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/connection</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/connection</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/consumer">Consumer</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/consumer</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/consumer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/exchange">Exchange</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/exchange</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"><p>An Exchange is a named entity 
within the Virtualhost which receives messages from producers and routes
 them to matching Queues within the Virtualhost.</p><p>The server provides a set of exchange types with each exchange type implementing a different routing algorithm.</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/exchange</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/group">Group</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/group</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/groupmember">GroupMember</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/groupmember</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/groupmember</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/groupprovider">GroupProvider</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/groupprovider</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/groupprovider</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/keystore">KeyStore</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/keystore</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/keystore</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/plugin">Plugin</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/plugin</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/plugin</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/port">Port</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/port</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"><p>The Broker supports configuration
 of Ports to specify the particular AMQP messaging and HTTP/JMX 
management connectivity it offers for use.</p><p>Each Port is configured
 with the particular Protocols and Transports it supports, as well as 
the Authentication Provider to be used to authenticate connections. 
Where SSL is in use, the Port configuration also defines which Keystore 
to use and (where supported) which TrustStore(s) and whether Client 
Certificates should be requested/required.</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/port</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/preferencesprovider">PreferencesProvider</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/preferencesprovider</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/preferencesprovider</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/publisher">Publisher</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/publisher</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/publisher</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/queue">Queue</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/queue</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"><p>Queues are named entities within a
 VirtualHost that hold/buffer messages for later delivery to consumer 
applications. Consumers subscribe to a queue in order to receive 
messages for it.</p><p>The Broker supports different queue types, each 
with different delivery semantics. It also allows for messages on a 
queue to be treated as a group.</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/queue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/remotereplicationnode">RemoteReplicationNode</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/remotereplicationnode</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/remotereplicationnode</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/session">Session</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/session</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/session</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/truststore">TrustStore</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/truststore</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/truststore</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/user">User</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/user</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/user</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/virtualhost">VirtualHost</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/virtualhost</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"><p>A virtualhost is a namespace in 
which messaging is performed. Virtualhosts are independent; the 
messaging goes on a within a virtualhost is independent of any messaging
 that goes on in another virtualhost. For instance, a queue named <i>foo</i> defined in one virtualhost is completely independent of a queue named <i>foo</i> in another virtualhost.</p><p>A virtualhost is backed by storage which is used to store the messages.</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/virtualhost</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/virtualhostalias">VirtualHostAlias</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/virtualhostalias</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/virtualhostalias</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/virtualhostloginclusionrule">VirtualHostLogInclusionRule</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/virtualhostloginclusionrule</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/virtualhostloginclusionrule</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/virtualhostlogger">VirtualHostLogger</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/virtualhostlogger</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/virtualhostlogger</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="type" rowspan="2"><a href="http://localhost:8080/apidocs/latest/virtualhostnode">VirtualHostNode</a></td>
<td class="path">/api/latest/virtualhostnode</td>
<td class="description" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="path">/api/v6/virtualhostnode</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


</body></html>
```

Comment: This isn't an actual question. You should either A. Ask a question/Post an answer, or B. Use the documentation service and add documentation there.